# How to get MAX Data where Max ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I want get some of data with one `distinct` email.

My code is below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Email, 
                Degree, 
                Majority
FROM   job_education a 
WHERE  a.Status = 'Active' 
AND a.IdEducationLevel = (
                          SELECT Max(b.IdEducationLevel) 
                          FROM job_education b 
                          WHERE b.Status='Active' 
                          AND  a.Email = b.Email
                         )
```

Thanks your kindness before

Comment: it would be great if you could provide us some sample data, and expected output

Comment: You lost me at 'wanna'.

Comment: And what is the issue with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be fine, although I would fix the table aliases:

```
SELECT je.*
FROM job_education je
WHERE je.Status = 'Active' AND
      je.IdEducationLevel = (SELECT MAX(je2.IdEducationLevel)
                             FROM job_education je2
                             WHERE je2.Status = 'Active' AND je2.Email = je.Email
                            );
```

If you are getting multiple rows for a given email -- and you want only one row -- then use a better id in the subquery:

```
SELECT je.*
FROM job_education je
WHERE je.Status = 'Active' AND
      je.job_education_id = (SELECT je2.job_education_id
                             FROM job_education je2
                             WHERE je2.Status = 'Active' AND je2.Email = je.Email
                             ORDER BY IdEducationLevel DESC, job_education_id DESC
                             LIMIT 1
                            );
```

I have invented an id called `job_education_id` for this purpose.  Note that this query uses `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` rather than an aggregation function.

Answer (score 1):

you should use a join
(the subselect can't see the upper reference to the table a)

```
SELECT DISTINCT Email, 
            Degree, 
            Majority 
     FROM   job_education a 
     INNER JOIN (
        SELECT  b.Email,  Max(b.IdEducationLevel)  max_IdEducationLevel
        FROM job_education b 
        WHERE b.Status='Active' 
        GROUP BY b.Email

     ) t  ON    a.Email = t.Email and a.IdEducationLevel = t.maxy_IdEducationLevel
     WHERE  a.Status = 'Active'
```